# Why $\dim V^G = Trace(\varphi)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $V^G = \{v \in V: \pi(g)v = v, \forall g \in G \}$. Here $(\pi, V)$  is a representation of $G$. Let $\varphi = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \pi(g)$.
How to show that $\dim V^G = Trace(\varphi)$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P:V\to V$ is a [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29) then $V=\ker P\oplus {\rm img}\,P$ on which $P$ acts as $0\oplus{\rm Id}$.

Here $\varphi$ is a projection with ${\rm img}\,\varphi=V^G$. Therefore ${\rm tr}(\varphi)={\rm tr}({\rm Id}_{V^G})=\dim V^G$.